# How can I install nautilus in Kubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, nautilus

I recently switched to Kubuntu 17.04 it's amazing but I didn't like dolphin (file manager that comes with KDE suite), so I tried to install Nautilus by doing This

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

This should have installed Nautilus but it gave me an error

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does this actually mean? Will I not be able to install Nautilus in Kubuntu 17.04?

Comment: @Zanna is nautilus available without any PPA in Kubuntu?

Comment: @Zanna seems like i complicated things, *again*

Comment: @Zanna that's an embarrassing answer

Comment: @should Yeah, right. Should we clean the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's available in default repositories, so no need to add any PPA.

First of all delete the added PPA by running the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

then install Nautilus from normal repository with the following command:

```
sudo apt install nautilus
```