# Kubuntu 17.04 Not installing some Apps from PPA

Tags: apt, software-installation, kubuntu, ppa

I recently moved to Kubuntu and I'm having this situation where i'm unablto Install anything from a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install mpv
```

PPA gets added `apt-get update` works as it should but Apps don't get installed

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Full output posted here at [Paste Ubuntu](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24465327/)

Same happened in this situation  [How can I install nautilus in Kubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/909058/665251)

I know that MPVplayer and Nautilus are available on default repositories but MPV has newer version on PPA or maybe i'm completely wronge and this is suppose to happen in Kubuntu and they prefer default repositories over PPA, and MPV PPA used to work in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. How can I resolve this situation?

---

Strangely this PPA worked

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install smplayer smplayer-themes smplayer-skins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad (I don't know what else to call it) PPA in your system

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
```

You should remove that PPA and then try again.

I can help you if you give the list of PPA's that you have by doing

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Comment: `ppa:noobslab/apps` found it and removed it , install worked, thanks